# Why does \begin{figure} center my image vertically?

Tags: floats, captions, vertical-alignment

If I insert image into my document as such:

```
\includegraphics{spss24fore.png}
```

The image is aligned at top of the page, but when I use:

```
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{spss24fore.png}
        \caption{Kuva 1.1}
\end{figure}
```

to get the caption to the picture as well, the image moves vertically down more towards the center of the page and more to the left?...Why so?...I only want to add caption for the image, I want it to stay where it is =)

Comment: Maybe this answer will help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8631/9517

Comment: +1 Indeed it did! Thank you for your answer =) It worked when I started to use `\begin{minipage}` and `\captionof` as in the link you gave instructed =)